# Bug with NEST's PolygonShape

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Good day:

I'm trying to save object with a `Polygon` shape. Whenever I try to save this, I get error `failed to parse [serviceAreas]`. This property is on a POCO which is defined as

```
/// <summary>
///  Used for Service Locations 
/// </summary>
[GeoShape]
public PolygonGeoShape ServiceAreas { get; set; }
```

And this is what's generated on saving the property:

```
"serviceAreas":{  
          "coordinates":[  
             [  
                {  
                   "lat":34.070222,
                   "lon":-118.286448
                },
                {  
                   "lat":34.070649,
                   "lon":-118.203192
                },
                {  
                   "lat":34.022147,
                   "lon":-118.203878
                },
                {  
                   "lat":34.019016,
                   "lon":-118.277349
                },
                {  
                   "lat":34.070222,
                   "lon":-118.286448
                }
             ]
          ],
          "type":"polygon",
          "ignoreUnmapped":null
       },
```

Detail error is this:

```
failed to parse [serviceAreas]","caused_by":{"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Current token (START_OBJECT) not numeric, can not use numeric value accessors\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.BytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper@1ea7ae53
```

Problem is, when I remove `lat` and `lon` in the JSON output like so:

```
"serviceAreas":{  
      "coordinates":[  
         [  
            [  
              34.070222,
              -118.286448
            ],
            [  
               34.070649,
               -118.203192
            ],
            [  
               34.022147,
               -118.203878
            ],
            [  
             34.019016,
             -118.277349
            ],
            [  
             34.070222,
             -118.286448
            ]
         ]
      ],
```

It works. Thoughts? I'm using ElasticSearch version 6.3.2 with NEST 6.1.0.

Comment: what does your `ConnectionSettings` look like?

Comment: `new ConnectionSettings(pool, (builtin, settings) => new JsonNetSerializer(builtin, settings,
            contractJsonConverters: new JsonConverter[] { new StringEnumConverter() }))`

Comment: Also removing this solve the issue. There's a bug with the serializer.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see this using NEST 6.2.0: https://gist.github.com/russcam/bd2e587e33324263aaeaa561085d4e56

Comment: Is this available over NUGET? The latest version I'm seeing is 6.1.0

Comment: yes: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST/6.2.0. You'll need .NET 4.6 or NetStandard 1.3 compatible TFM. .NET 4.5 is not supported in 6.2.0